# Big O notation constants

Tags: big-o

Given the following functions f(n) and g(n), is f in O(g(n)) or is f in Θ(g(n)),
or both? If true, specify a constant c and point n0, if false, briefly specify why.

(a) f(n) = 2n , g(n) = 2^2n

(b) f(n) = n!, g(n) = 2n

I do understand for (a), f(n) = O(g(n)) because g(n) upper bounds f(n)
and for (b), g(n) = O(f(n)) because of dominance relativity on the fact that n! > 2^n..

I have done some research but could not find much on how to calculate the constants c and n0 for this type of questions. thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)  f(n) = 2n , g(n) = 2^(2n)

(I added parenthesis.)

```
f(n) = O(g(n)) iff | f(n) | <= C * | g(n) | for some C>0 and all n > n0

2n <= 1*(2^(2n)) for n>1
```

Therefore 2n = O(2^(2n)). My constants are `C=1` and `n0 = 1`. But others work too.

Comment: @MFisherDx that makes sense, but I am wondering if other constants would be correct in this case as well for example if i want to be safe and not sure about the constants, putting c = 4 and n0 = 5... would it be a decent answer or not?

Comment: Yeah. Those numbers work too. Plot both functions on a graph. Scale `g` by any constant C. If there a point where `f` is always less than or equal to `g` then `f(n) is O(g(n))`